# ¿Como puedo hacer que se cierre sesion por inactividad en laravel?

Tags: laravel-7

Tengo un login ya funcionando, pero quisiera saber como implementar el cierre e sesión por inactividad y que me redirija a la pagina de inicio de sesión, ya probe cambiando el .env el tiempo y en sesion.php que esta en config, pero algo no esta funcionando y nose como redirigir, soy nueva en laravel y me confunde algo :(, el lifetime es por minutos cierto??
quiero asegurar por lo que investigue si jsjs

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1
```

SESSION.PHP

```
lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 1),

    'expire_on_close' => true,
```